# JavaScript Math functions outputs different float numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to do trigonometry in JavaScript. When I try run this code in the terminal:

```
function angle(deg, min, sec) { return (deg) + (min / 60) + (sec / 3600); }

let deg2 = 89, min2 = 45, sec2 = 0, dist2 = 11.27;
let lat2 = (Math.sin(angle(deg2, min2, sec2))) * dist2;
let long2 = (Math.cos(angle(deg2, min2, sec2))) * dist2;
console.log("lat2 , long2 : " + lat2 + "  ,  " + long2);
```

I get this:

```
lat2 , long2 : 11.011462356910855  ,  -2.400124322266507
```

instead of this:

```
lat2 , long2 : 11.269892717722677  ,  0.049174495639093
```

I tried swapping the `cos` and `sin` with each other but no luck. Also tried to replace `cos` with `tan` and still different result. Also replaced `sin` with `tan` and still not correct.

Comment: The argument to trigonometrical functions like `Math.sin` must be in radians, not in degrees. 180 degrees = Math.PI radians.

Comment: Math.sin/cos work with radians - and so should you. Radians are better than degrees because (a) radians can be used to calculate the distance you've traveled around a circle, and (b) because radians are based in the circumference of the unit circle, they don't involve defining new type of unit (i.e. degrees - which by the way derive from the Babylonian calendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break your problem into smaller chunks.

Create functions for converting:

- Sexagesimal degrees (DMS) to decimal degrees
- Decimal degrees to radians
- Radians and distance to coordinates (latitude and longitude)

**Note:** Functions that end with a "2" are "overloaded methods" that take an object instead of a list of parameters. This is for purely for convenience.

```js
const
  toDecimalDegrees = (degrees, minutes, seconds) =>
    degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600),
  toDecimalDegrees2 = ({ degrees, minutes, seconds }) =>
    toDecimalDegrees(degrees, minutes, seconds),
  toRadians = (degrees) =>
    degrees * (Math.PI / 180),
  toCoordinates = (degrees, minutes, seconds, distance = 0) =>
    (angle => ({
      latitude: Math.sin(angle) * distance,
      longitude: Math.cos(angle) * distance
    }))
    (toRadians(toDecimalDegrees(degrees, minutes, seconds))),
  toCoordinates2 = ({ degrees, minutes, seconds }, distance) =>
    toCoordinates(degrees, minutes, seconds, distance);

const
  angle       = { degrees: 89, minutes: 45, seconds: 0 },
  distance    = 11.27,
  coordinates = toCoordinates2(angle, distance);

console.log(coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigonometry functions expects the angle in radians not degrees.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos

```js
function angle(deg, min, sec) {
    return (deg) + (min / 60) + (sec / 3600);
}

let deg2 = 89,
    min2 = 45,
    sec2 = 0,
    dist2 = 11.27;
let lat2 = Math.sin(Math.PI * angle(deg2, min2, sec2) / 180) * dist2;
let long2 = Math.cos(Math.PI * angle(deg2, min2, sec2) / 180) * dist2;

console.log("lat2 , long2 : " + lat2 + "  ,  " + long2);
```